# PHP: looking up values in DB and converting before inserting data

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

This might be easier to do with javascript but but I happen to be restricted solely to MySQL, PHP, and Apache (as well as HTML and CSS obviously) for this project, and I'm not good at PHP

I've basically finished the whole thing but came a cross a small problem.

The user creates a sport event and to do so the user chooses two opposing teams with the help of two html dropdowns (both dropdowns display the same array of teams that are fetched from my 'teams' table located in my database). The names of the teams are displayed and selected on the page, and therefore stored as string variables in PHP once the user submits the form.

Here's the catch, the two teams the user selects are then to be saved in a table which is meant to contain the IDs of the two teams, rather than their names (makes it easier to enforce integrity constraints). But I would have to query the db again to obtain the IDs from the 'teams' table and then store this in the table I'm interested in.

What makes this a tad more complicated is the fact that along with the two team-dropdowns, in the aforementioned html form, the user inputs a lot of other data regarding the event which is stored together with the two teams; this data is supposed to be inserted into the same database table as is, everything but the two teams is supposed to be inserted as is.

My initial thoughts were to add a subquery next to the two value placeholders I would use to insert the teams-data:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sport_events
          (event_date, start_time, end_time, home_team, visiting_team) values
          (?, ?, ?, (select ID from teams where team_name = ?), (select ID from teams where team_name =?))";
```

this returns an error however:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

which makes no sense. if I try to insert the same tuple into the database manually (using these two subqueries in mysql) everything is fine:

```sql
('xyz_date', 'xyz_time', 'xyz_time', (select ID from teams where team_name = 'Manchester United'), (select ID from teams where team_name = 'Arsenal'))
```

if I try to query the database using either one of the two subqueries, the result is always one row as the team_name is always unique (below is the query):

```sql
select ID from teams where team_name = 'Manchester United';
```

EDIT: here's the code

How the teams are fetched and displayed in two html dropdowns:

```
        $teams = array();
/*populate an array with the teams from the database*/
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {
          array_push($teams, $row['team_name']);
        }
        echo '<p>Home Team: <select name="home_team" value ="">';
/*unload the teams into the html element - first dropdown*/
        foreach ($teams as $team) {
          echo '<option>' . $team . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select></p>';
/*unload the teams into the html element - second dropdown*/
        echo '<p>Visiting Team: <select name="visiting_team" value ="">';
        foreach ($teams as $team) {
          echo '<option>' . $team . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select></p>';
```

the five pieces of data inserted by the user into the form are then checked for null-values (example of one below)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if(empty($_POST['home_team'])) {
        $data_missing[] = 'Home Team';
      }
      else {
        $h_team = trim($_POST['home_team']);
      }
...
```

and then this is as far as the data gets

```
if(empty($data_missing)){
        require_once('mysqli_connect.php');
        $query = "INSERT INTO sport_events
          (event_date, start_time, end_time, home_team, visiting_team) values
          (?, ?, ?, (select ID from teams where team_name = ?), (select ID from teams where team_name =?))";

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssii", $e_date, $beg_at,
        $end_at, $h_team, $v_team);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
```

P.S. using MySQL 10.4.14 connected to the XAMPP 3.2.4 using Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.2.34

Comment: share more codes. with your explanation, problem is in your params for execution the query.

Comment: ok added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `value` for an `<option>`, and then it's the value which is submitted to the server with the form.

So if you put the ID of your team into each option when you are rendering the HTML, then you'll get the selected ID back again when the form is submitted.

e.g.

```
<option value="1">Anywhere United</option>
<option value="2">SomewhereElse Rangers</option>
<option value="3">Lonely Wanderers</option>
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

The current SQL used to select the teams isn't shown, but I would guess the SQL query to do this needs to be something like:

```
SELECT ID, team_name FROM teams
```

and then the PHP to read it:

```
$teams = array();
/*populate an array with the teams from the database*/
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {
  array_push($teams, $row);
}
echo '<p>Home Team: <select name="home_team" value ="">';


/*unload the teams into the html element - first dropdown*/
foreach ($teams as $team) {
  echo '<option value="' . $team['ID'] . '">' . $team['team_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select></p>';


/*unload the teams into the html element - second dropdown*/
echo '<p>Visiting Team: <select name="visiting_team" value ="">';
foreach ($teams as $team) {
  echo '<option value="' . $team['ID'] . '">' . $team['team_name'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select></p>';
```

Comment: Populate the drop down from db select.

Comment: @Biaaach that's just an example of how your HTML needs to end up looking. You can use PHP to make the HTML look like this. Unfortunately I can't see the SQL query you use to select the teams currently, so I can't advise you precisely how to change it - otherwise I would have done so. I did say "put the ID of your team into each option when you are rendering the HTML" - I meant rendering it dynamically with PHP, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @ADyson ooh okay, my apologies, that will work, thanks so much for the advice. my thinking was totally backwards. the sql query is literally just ```SELECT team_name FROM teams;```

Comment: @Biaaach I added a clearer example based on what I think the query probably is, from looking at your other code, and what the resulting PHP to process it would be. See the updated answer.

Comment: thank you @ADyson, you've really helped me out!

Comment: @ADyson okay so in actuality this produces an unexpected result: the dropdown now contains the IDs (integers) and the first letters of each team. They're displayed like so: ID, name of team with that id, another ID, name of team with the corresponding ID, ...

Comment: @Biaaach Yes sorry you should really be using mysqli_fetch_assoc for this. Your original shouldn't have been working without that, which is odd. Anyway I did make a typo in my original version, I edited it shortly after I posted it. Check if you're using the latest version or not. If you look at the revision history of the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65620103/revisions you can see what I changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227026/discussion-between-biaaach-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1):

I would do this completely different.  I did so for categories of a classifieds page.

And i think you already have all prerequisites.

First get all values of the table teams.

```
SELECT ID, teams from teams
```

Store it into an array.

Then construct your 2 select dropdowns from that array  - the value is the ID the display is the teams name   your users will not see any difference
the function returns only the options- the select line is put into the code/template

So you will have the ids on hand and do not have to do 2 expensive text search subqueries.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sport_events
          (event_date, start_time, end_time, home_team, visiting_team) values
          (?, ?, ?, ?, ?))";
```

No database change needed.
No problems with subqueries
Dropdowns filled automatically  - if you have a new team just insert one line in the db and it will be there  :-)

Comment: ok wow that's much better, how would I go about separating the team ID from the team name though? once the user has selected the team name I no longer care about it and just want to insert the corresponding IDs?

Comment: yep, I've got to fetch the ID as well no other way. Danke dir!!